# Strange touchpad behavior - writing "y" on gesture

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad, tablet

I've got a Odys Wintab running Windows 8.1 RTM. I've also bought the keyboard and touchpad case, clicking, two finger scrolling and displaying the charms works perfectly. There is only one strange behaviour: When I slide in from the top, instead of moving the mouse or doing some else it writes an "y". If you have capslock enabled, it is even a capital letter!
It seems to me the touchpad is not using any other drivers than included in Windows. Actually it in device manager it is displayed as "HID conform mouse". What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have it too.

It sends the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> key combination. You can overwrite its behavior using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

I am using the following code:

```
#y::
return
```

a more complete approach i ended up ( disabling app swicth):

```
;win+y -> pull down
;win+c -> pull from right - charms (touchscreen still allows it)
#y::
#c::
SendInput, {Win up}
return
```

edit:

Btw, the App-Switching (Pull from left) can be disabled in the Win8 "Hot corners" settings.

Using AutoHotkey, i also added hotkeys for the missing <kbd><|></kbd> key.  <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (shift, alt, ctrl) for the different key states.

Comment: Is ⊞ Win+Y a hotkey for windows? Why should a touchpad send such keys if they are useless?

Comment: the topic about this is Precision-Touchpad (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn467317(v=vs.85).aspx / http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-8/touchpad). The Metro Startpage uses these commands.